# Is it possible to use a gigabit connection on 10/100 load balancer?

Tags: ethernet

My ISP provides a connection output of 1000BASE-T.
I am trying to feed this to a load balancer device that only supports a 10/100 connection. However, the connection is not detected.

I am afraid this is because the load balancer only supports a 10/100 connection.

Is it possible to convert the gigabit output to the 10/100 connection?

Comment: Apparently, one side or the other does not support auto-negotiation, which is supposed to be required for 1000Base-T. You may be able to put a gigbit switch between the ISP connection and the load balancer, but I would _**strongly**_ suggest that you place a firewall as the device connecting to the ISP. You are opening your business to attack (the attacks start immediately upon connecting to the Internet).

Comment: Not all 1000BaseT chipsets support 10 and 100Mbps. Especially if it's a TenGigE/GigE interface, there's good chance it won't support those low speeds.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

If one side only supports 1000BASE-T and the other only 10BASE-T/100BASE-TX you can use just about any gigabit switch to 'adapt' in between. Note however, that the connection cannot work faster than 100 Mbit/s.

Since that link is likely *outside your firewall* do not use your production switch unless you separate that traffic into a VLAN of its own.

It's a bit strange that the ISP connection supports 1000BASE-T only since practically all twisted-pair ports support 10/100/1000 but you'll need to ask your ISP about that (unless it's a 10G port which often only negotiates down to 1G).

Comment: I suspect the port in question is on a media converter. While 1000base-T ports on switches, routers hosts etc nearly always support lower speeds, media converters generally don't.